# How to handle URL differences from DEV to LIVE environments?

Tags: spring-mvc, java-ee-6

I'm less experienced with Java.  Currently in my app all of my URLs are set to things like `http://localhost:8080/cmt/content/3068fc93/edit.html`

On LIVE, my url will need to go to `http://www.domain.com/content/3068fc93/edit.html`

This is my first java app and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.  I'd like to just be able to link to pages using an absolute path (without a domain) such as `/content/3068fc93.html`.

**update**

Anytime I do `<a href='/content/edit.html'>Edit Content</a>` it will work on LIVE but not on DEV because DEV requires the extra `/cmt`.  How do I fix this between my 2 environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use jstl tag as :

```
<a href="<c:url value='/content/3068fc93.html'/>">Welcome</a>
```

where 'c' came from `<%@ taglib prefix="c"          uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

**Update**

about the cmt portion, you should a rewritte url or change your url param on the servlet mapping

**Update**
in prod you got :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>web-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in dev you must have :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>web-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cmt/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how to change the URL via the servlet mapping?

Comment: updated my answer, you can do it with servlet-mapping in your web.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the Spring URL tag, here are the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/UrlTag.html).

So for your case:

```
<spring:url value="/content/{contentId}/edit.html">
   <spring:param name="contentId" value="3068fc93" />
</spring:url>
```

Comment: Alex - The issue I'm having is not that portion of the URL.  The issue is the `/cmt` vs not having that extra URL piece.

Comment: I think using that tag will take care of that for you.

Comment: How do we know that the OP is using Spring? to answer myself: because the question is tagged with spring-mvc. ;-)